# Всё(,) что требуется от вас(,) – лишь сделать это.

Tags: запятая

Нужны ли эти запятые?

Answer (score 3):

Да, разумеется, нужны и поставлены правильно. В данном случае запятая перед тире закрывает оборот "что требуется от вас".

Comment: Спасибо, просто я думала, что, может, "всё что требуется" - это неделимое сочетание.

Comment: запятые выделяют придаточное предложение.

Comment: После придаточного идёт частица ЛИШЬ. По правилу тире не ставится,  если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоит вводное слово, наречие, союз, частица. Всё, что требуется от вас, лишь сделать это.**

Comment: А можно ссылку на это правило?

Comment: Катя процитировала почти дословно это правило, которое я помню по Розенталю. Единственное, что нужно добавить, это то, что данное правило Розенталь предлагает применять для тех случаев, когда подлежащее и сказуемое выражены именами существительными.

Comment: Всё здесь по правилам, и тире тоже. Оно акцентное,разделяет предложение на 2 части, акцентируя внимание на второй части, хочется вставить "это".